# How to use select update and insert query together in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have three table like table1,table2 and table3.

What I want to do is if table1 record is found in table2 then insert in table3 and update a flag in table1.

How can I do it using MySQL.

Comment: create a transaction and do it. Anything wrong with this?

Comment: Do you want/need to do it all in a single query? (your topic seems to imply that)

Comment: I am expecting this using single query.

Comment: Expecting? but haven't tried anything?

Comment: Not getting exact idea how to implement it but i want to implement it.

Comment: Try create some procedure dude. Because single query was too risk for doing those kind transaction together, try search Google for `tutorial making procedure on MySQL`

Answer (score 1):

It is not a single query, But using stored procedures you can achieve the task

Create a procedure (Assuming you have a foreign_key in table2)

```
delimiter //
 create procedure my_proc()
     begin
     select @a := (select GROUP_CONCAT(t1.id) from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id != t2.foreign_key);
     insert into table3 select * from table1 where FIND_IN_SET(id,@a);
     update table1 set flag=1 where FIND_IN_SET(id,@a);
 end//
```

And call it

```
 delimiter ;
 call my_proc();
```

Comment: humm i am expecting it using single query but ok i will go with your solution thanks

Comment: its not possible with single query! another choice would be transaction

Answer (score 0):

your a not able to insert in one table and update another table in single sql statement.
but you have at least two options:

1. using transaction (include insert into table3 and update table1)
2. using trigger on table3 on insert (updat table